# Mongo $addField For nested structured data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a result like below, Is there any way I can change the `_id` value which is the same for the all nested data. I want to rename each id with some other name not simply `_id`

```
{
     "items": [
                {
                    "_id": "5bd1a3da2901d60f9edc4d10",
                    "addons": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5bd1a3da2901d60f9edc4d96",
                            "options": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5bd1a3da2901d60f9edc4d98",
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ] 
    }
```

Here in the above code, I tried `$addfields` attribute but it works fine only for the topmost nesting 
Here is the code I've tried:

```
Items.aggregate([
            { 
                $match: {  _id: '123'}
            },      
            { $addFields: { item_id: "$_id" , 
                            "addons.addon_id" :  "$addons._id" , 
                   "addons.options.options_id" : "$addons.options._id" 
                 } 
             },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0
                }
            },
        ],
```

This code works fine and added item_id in the root element but added addon and option_id as an array value,

```
{
    "item_list": [
        {
            "_id": "5bd1a3da2901d60f9edc4d10",
            "addons": [
                {
                    "_id": "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9a",
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9b",
                            "options_id": [
                                [
                                    "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9b"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "addon_id": [
                        "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9a"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I got something like this a nested array of addon_id and options_id, I want it to be a simple string and not array,

```
{
    "item_list": [
        {
            "_id": "5bd1a3da2901d60f9edc4d10",
            "addons": [
                {
                    "_id": "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9a",
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9b",
                            "options_id": "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9b"
                        }
                    ],
                    "addon_id": "5bd1a44b2901d60f9edc4d9a"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Am expecting the above result.